# Limit of two sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

1. $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n} $ . I think the limit is $4$. I did :
   $ \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n} = 4 \sqrt[n]{(\frac{3}{4}) ^n+1}$ .Am I right?
2. $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1\cdot 4 } + \frac{1}{4\cdot 7} +...+\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}  $. I know that for each $k$ , this sequence is the sum of $k$ terms, the smallest one is $ \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}  $, and the largest is $ \frac{1}{1. 4 }$ . But when substituting and trying to use the squeeze thm, I get that the limit should be between $0$ and $\infty$, which gives me nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second limit is a infinite sum. It might help to partialize the fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Your first limit is correct.

2- As I suggested in the comments, you have to partialize the fractions into two, as such:

$$\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n-2)}= \frac{1}{3} \left(\dfrac{-1}{(3n+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(3n-2)}\right)$$

Using the fact that it is a telescoping sum, you now have to find the:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{(3n+1)}+\frac{1}{(3n-2)}\right)$$

Listing out the first few terms and the $n$-th term the cancellations become clear,

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left[\frac{-1}{4} +\frac{-1}{7}+\frac{-1}{10}...\frac{-1}{3n-2} +\frac{-1}{3n+1} \right] + \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7}+...\frac{1}{3n-2} \right]$$

$$=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)=1$$

Therefore, the final sum is $\dfrac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For the second one use this fact that :
$$\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n-2)}=\frac{-1}{3(3n+1)}+\frac{1}{3(3n-2)}$$ So the sum can be reduced to this one: $$S_n=\frac{1}3\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n-2)}\right)$$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for your consideration. I typed it but some of my thoughts were refused by my Prof. I have been correcting the facts these days.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n$
$$
4^n<3^n+4^n< 2\cdot 4^n,
$$
thus
$$
4<\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}< 2^{1/n}\cdot 4.
$$

Comment: Is something wrong with the OP's answer?

Comment: @user2943324 - You need to show that $\lim\sqrt[n]{(\frac{3}{4}) ^n+1}=1$. And that you show similarly to what Yiorgos S. Smyrlis did: $\sqrt[n]{1}<\sqrt[n]{(\frac{3}{4}) ^n+1}<\sqrt[n]{2}$

Comment: Oh! Of course. Thank you.